# How to jump to initialization of an variable in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

How to navigate to the **initialization** of a variable **NOT** its **declaration**?

I see people using the text search and try to find each assignment and I tend to find the **usages** of that variable and filter by hand the assignments to it. Both ways are not practical.

Is there any **shortcut** or usage search way of doing this faster?

Comment: how could there be? there can be hundreds of them for each variable. How would IntelliJ know which one you want?
What you can do, is select the variable name, and the other usages will be highlighted on the right.

Comment: @Stultuske well of curse but this view is not a structured

Comment: you neglect to reflect on the most critical part of my response: "how could there be?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold `ctrl` and `mouse click` the instance of the variable. This will bring you to where the variable is created. If you initialized it later in the code, hold `ctrl` and `mouse click` the variable again (where it is created) and it will show you options of all places in the code where the variable is used - just click on the **top one**, which is likely the initialization.

Comment: the top one is likely the initialization .... you're aware that code in Java can be separated in methods, and they don't have to be "in order"? You're also aware that one variable (unless it's final) can be re-initialized?

Comment: Is there a keyboard shortcut for that?

Comment: @Shane Monks O'Byrne got it, as well as in find usages you can then filter by write access (STRG+W)

Comment: https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Comment: @stultuske I am aware, that's why I said "likely". The list of usages are ordered numerically, from line 0->∞ .But yes, it is entirely possible that the variable is initialized in a method further down in the code. You can see a sample code snippet in the list of suggestions when Ctrl clicking the variable; this may also show you where the variable is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

To specifically look at the data flow, (as opposed to just searching by symbol or text visually)

You can invoke [Dataflow to Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/analyzing-data-flow.html#d12827e94)

Whilst there is no default keyboard shortcut, it will attempt to actually watch the data flow.

[image]